# How to pass complex JSON in Unity while using web api

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

There is method defined in REST(WEB API) using C#.

Here I am trying to post following complex data as string in unity C# script using wwwform, but I am not able to send/post following

```
string  abc = "[{";
 for (int i = 0; i < SessionNeedles.Count; i++)
        {
            abc += "\"PositionX\":\"" + SessionNeedles[i].PositionX + "\",";
            abc += "\"PositionY\":\"" + SessionNeedles[i].PositionY + "\",";
            abc += "\"PositionZ\":\"" + SessionNeedles[i].PositionZ + "\",";
            abc += "\"RotationX\":\"" + SessionNeedles[i].RotationX + "\",";
            abc += "\"RotationY\":\"" + SessionNeedles[i].RotationY + "\",";
            abc += "\"RotationZ\":\"" + SessionNeedles[i].RotationZ + "\",";
            abc += "\"RotationW\":\"" + SessionNeedles[i].RotationW + "\",";
            abc += "\"ScaleX\":\"" + SessionNeedles[i].ScaleX + "\",";
            abc += "\"ScaleY\":\"" + SessionNeedles[i].ScaleY + "\",";
            abc += "\"ScaleZ\":\"" + SessionNeedles[i].ScaleZ + "\",";
            abc += "\"Prefab\":\"" + SessionNeedles[i].Prefab + "\",";
            abc += "\"NeedleName\":\"" + SessionNeedles[i].NeedleName + "\"";
            abc += "},{";
        }
        abc = abc.Substring(0, abc.Length - 2) + "]";
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("Duration", 5);
        form.AddField("PatientId", "7");
        form.AddField("SessionNeedles", abc);
        WWW www = new WWW(_AddSessionUrl, form);
        StartCoroutine("AddSession", www);
```

Comment: You need to make your form and www inside the IEnumerator and wait for completed.

Comment: Please pass me an example. would be very helpful for me. AddSession is already an Ienumrator.  IEnumerator AddSession(WWW www)
    {
        yield return www;
        if (www.error == null)
        {
            print("Done");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("WWW Error: " + www.error);

        }
    }

Comment: you have this on the documentation, check this link:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html

Answer (score 0):

1. I am not sure what you mean by "not being able to send".
   Do you get an error on Unity's end? On the server?
2. Please use a JSON serialization library (ie. [JSON.NET](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/11347), [SimpleJSON](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON) <-- haven't tried it out, but I wanted to share a free option as well), it will make you code much more readable and maintainable; you might have a syntax error in it.
3. You did not attach the coroutine code, but you have to either `yield return www;`
4. If there are still no errors use a packet sniffer (ie. [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) / [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)) and see what data is being sent from your Unity client